# Why does my circular saw motor turn but the blade does not?

Tags: powertools, circular-saw

I have a McKellar circular saw. I was ripping up some old pallets for firewood. and thought the blade had jammed.  I stopped, took the blade out of the work and tried again and the motor goes and the blade turns for a second or two. Then the blade stops turning but the motor noise remains unchanged. I wait a bit, and the same thing happens. The motor is OK. The switch is OK

What do I do?

Comment: Check the diamond knock-out on the saw blade.  I've had these break out before.

Answer (score 7):

It is very likely, that the fixating screw/disk is loose. **Do not operate the saw in this state. It is dangerous.**

A circular saw usually has a direct drive. I.e. the motor spindle is also the center shaft for the blade. So if your motor is spinning, but not the blade, it means the blade has lost contact to the shaft.

Check if the blade is properly centered and aligned with all locating pins (if your saw has some). Then fixate the screw using the appropriate wrenches.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the particular saw you have, and how loose your teminology .vs. industry standard terminology is, you may have a worm drive saw (that you call a circular saw - the blade is still circular), or a circular saw with a gear reduction built in that isn't a worm-drive - in either case you could have broken gears if there is a reduction gear step in the drive train. The precise model of your saw (rather than just the brand-name) would be helpful in determining if this could be the case.

The brand name might be "McKell**e**r" not "McKell**a**r" based on some quick searching. At least the case in an ad for "McKellar saw" said McKeller quite legibly.[image] Perhaps there are two companies with confusing names, one being a knockoff brand - I'm not clear. Neither name seems to lead to a tool company website, which is not a great sign, IME.

Comment: Think I will take it for recycling and buy a new one.